# Unity container injection in my view models

Tags: mvvm, prism, viewmodel

I am a newcomer to C# / .Net / Prism / WPF / DevExpress and started to work on a big project in my company. As I am starting a bit late in the project, a lot of code was already produced and I stumble upon code like this very often:

```
public class AboutWindowViewModel : BindableBase
{
  public AboutWindowViewModel(IUnityContainer container)
  {
    ...
```

What I find "special" here is the dependence of the view model in the container. In the codebase I am currently looking at, it seems to be the "pattern". Every class gets a dependence in the `IUnityContainer` and then the dependencies are resolved manually with e.g.

```
container.ResolveEx<...>(...);
```

I am used to work with DI frameworks in other languages, so that example was just a non-sense to me because it goes against the definition of a DI framework and the problems it is meant to solve. For example, I tried to make up some code to test one of those view models and it turned out to be a nightmare.

Now, I addressed that concern to the developpers of my company and they answered me the following:

```
Prism recommendation is to resolve services using containers as they are needed.
```

Therefore, they resolve them all the time with the `IUnityContainer.ResolveEx` method.

My question is: is that really the recommended way to build up software with Prism??? If not, do you know where I can find documentation that clearly addresses that point with examples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is that really the recommended way to build up software with Prism???

Not at all, in it's an [anti-pattern](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorisanAnti-Pattern/).

> Prism recommendation is to resolve services using containers as they are needed.

Not really just Prism, but more generally, the recommendation is to *let the container resolve the dependencies*. Of course, this can be done by calling `Resolve` manually, but in doing that one defeats all the benefits expected from dependency injection.

Rather, you want to list the dependencies as constructor parameters and let the container fill them. Your code does *not* need to depend on the container, except for the very entry-point ("resolution root"). The application should only ever contain a single `Resolve` statement that resolves the first instance.

Here's where Prism comes into play: in your `PrismApplication.RegisterTypes` and `IModule.RegisterTypes`, you configure your container. You tell it which type should implement which interface. Later on, when view models are needed, Prism (the `ViewModelLocator` to be precise) uses the container to resolve the view models, thereby resolving all the dependencies. There's no reason to make any class depend on the container, in fact, Prism doesn't register anything for `IContainerRegistry` in the first place.

Keep in mind that the container can not only inject singleton services, but also transient instances or factories. And if you need parametrized factories, you can always manually create and register complex factories.

On a side-note, I, personally, would be hesitant to work for a client with a code-base like this, as it's an obvious proof that their developers have no idea what they're doing.